# send friend request on facebook from .csv file of user ids and emails

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a .csv file with all my contacts on it, listed by UID, Name and Email. Is there a way that I can send friend requests using this file?

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: Have you done any work ? or are you asking us to solve that? you can ask questions when you stuck not the whole programs..

Comment: I've a great idea! You got that CSV file means you got everything!
Now follow the steps given below:
1) Login to www.facebook.com
2) For each userID : userIDs
        copy the userID.
        make a url like www.facebook.com/userID
       Hit enter
       if the person is not friend
               send friend request
3) Done!!

Comment: @SubrataDey One hell of a solution !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send friend requests with the API, so it´s not possible at all. Not sure why anyone would want to do that anyway, to be honest...Sounds spammy, and afaik there is a protection against mass friendlisting on Facebook.